# Why this just closes the cmd after tipping the id?

Tags: batch-rename

```
@echo off
echo Type song ID:
set /p id=
for /r %userprofile%/AppData/Local/GeometryDash %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="%id%.mp3" 
set p=%%~dpnxa
if defined p (
echo Type NoNG song path:
set /p nong=
echo Type NoNG file name (with .mp3):
set /p songname=
cd %nong% 
ren %songname% %id%.mp3
::write move command here (just ignore)
pause
) else (
echo Song not found
pause
)
```

after tipping the id variable cmd just closes i tried to add pauses, exits everyware but nothing works i can't figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find anything with pause, it must be directly on the 3rd line.  As far as I understand it, you want to match the name and only continue when the name is found. I would recommend you this program line:

```
for /r %path% %%i in (%id%) do (
...
)
```

after that you can continue to work directly in the brackets with your variable